# When in the React component life cycle can I execute a route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have some kind of a wizard where each step has it's own route. Now when a user uses a direct link to the second step route, I would like to redirect him to the first step (using browserHistory.replace).

The problem I face is that I don't really know which stage in the components life cycle it should be performed. I have tried `constructor`, `render`, `componentWillMount`, but all of those do not prevent the component from rendering even if I use router. So what happens is that redirect occurs, but the component from the previous route still gets renders and fails (no data obviously).

Is there any "proper" way of redirecting during the component initialization (I need to check the state)? Or is there any other better way of doing so?

Comment: The best way would be to redirect on the server, which will presumably be hit when a user goes to a direct link. Is this something that's possible in your system? You can catch redirects on the server with `react-router` and send the appropriate response

Comment: If I do the redirect on the server, then it will be stored in history and the back button will be kind of a loop, that's why I use replace. I also have an absolutely ignorant server that just serves files (SPA).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the "official" recommended way (still interested if someone can find it), but what worked for me is this:

1. Redirect during `componentWillMount`
2. During render use the same condition as in `componentWillMount` to return null

Example:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    if (!this.props.data) {
      browserHistory.replace(myRoute);
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.data) {
      return (
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
      );
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is probably the earliest you'll have `this.props.data` (presumably from Redux) available to you so I think this is the best solution for now

Comment: You can actually get it in constructor, but React does not like redirects there :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik why react doesnot like redirects in constructor

Answer (score 1):

In v2/3 you should use the `onEnter` function to redirect (using the `replace` function). v2/3 replicates most of React's life cycle functions because it doesn't really use React to render route components. That is to say, `<Route>`s are just used for configuration and `react-router` generates an array of components for a given route and renders each individually.

```
function redirectToStart(nextState, replace) {
  if (!nextState.someCondition) {
    replace('/initial-page')
  }
}

<Route onEnter={redirectToStart} ... />
```

Comment: Problem with onEnter, is that I don't have the state there yet, so I'll need to somehow connect to redux store and extract it from there, effectively duplicating the logic for getting the state (that is used in component)

Comment: What sort of state? You can attach state to the `location`  used for navigation. When you navigate directly to a location, the state will be `null`. For example, when your wizard navigates from the first page to the second, you could add a `{ canLoad: true }` state to the location. When the second page's `onEnter` is called, it checks `nextState.canLoad` and redirects if that value is not `true`.

Comment: We had a discussion with my colleagues about component vs router to check for this things. And we ended up with a thought that it is a components job, rather than navigation which we wanted to not be aware of business logic too much. But I guess there are pros and cons in both approaches.

Comment: You can think of `onEnter` as a pseudo `componentWillMount`. v2/3 just replicates most of 'React' render out cycle because of how it works internally. In v4 you'll handle redirects in lifecycle methods. They actually even include a `<Redirect>` component to "render" a redirect.